# Растянуть img на всю высоту grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Откуда эти зазоры? Делал разными способами но они не исчезают

```css
.portfolio_pics {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 29px;
  grid-row-gap: 35px;

}

.portfolio_pics div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.portfolio_pics div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.portfolio_pics div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.portfolio_pics div:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio_pics">
          <div class="image"><img src="Assets/images/p1.jpg" class="image_content"></div>
          <div class="image"><img src="Assets/images/p2.jpg" class="image_content"></div>
          <div class="image"><img src="Assets/images/p3.jpg" class="image_content"></div>
          <div class="image"><img src="Assets/images/p4.jpg" class="image_content"></div>
          <div class="image"><img src="Assets/images/p5.jpg" class="image_content"></div>
          <div class="image"><img src="Assets/images/p6.jpg" class="image_content"></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

За зазоры между элементами grid отвечают свойства:

- `grid-column-gap`
- `grid-row-gap`
- или сокращенно `grid-gap`

Уберите их из ваших стилей и зазоров между элементами не будет.

Если вы про другое, то примените это к изображениям:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Блин. Плохо сформулировал. Имел ввиду зазор между картинками и границей элементов грида(по вертикали)

Comment: @JakeTheDog проверьте с object-tit и width: 100%; height: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

```css
.portfolio_pics div img { display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Так заработало

Answer (score 0):

Это из-за того, что тег `<img>` - `display: inline` по дефолту.
Чтобы избавиться от этого бага, используйте `display: block;`

```css
.pre {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.pre:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.pre p {
  max-width: 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.pre .img {
  background: red;
}

.pre.no-inline img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pre">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Inline">
  </div>
  <p>Эта картинка строчная, под ней есть красная полоска - это отступ от картинки.</p>
</div>

<div class="pre no-inline">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Block">
  </div>
  <p>Эта картинка блочная, под ней уже не будет полоски</p>
</div>
```